# How do i use my CSS file to change only a section of my HTML file?

Tags: html, css

This is my first attempt at making a website. I've made a file called style.css in which I wrote

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

the problem with this is that it changes the size of every image in the HTML file. how would I make it only affect one image or a few images?

Comment: You give the image an id -- IE `<img src="example.jpg" id="my_image_1">`  -- And call it in the CSS like --  `#my_image_1 {`

Comment: add class or id for every section then use it like `.services-section img` `.about-section img` and so on...

Comment: Voting to close as a direct duplicate of another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way CSS works is that it will apply the rule to all occurences of the selector you have provided.  Since all images use the `img` selector, all images are affected.

If you want to target a single image, or a group of images, you give them a class, like so:-

`<img class="red-border" src="...">`

And in your CSS:-

`.red-border {
   border: 1px solid red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `class` for change few images,for example :

> This css rule Affects any image that its `class` attribute value be `x`

```
.x { width:100%}

<img class="x" src="..."> <-------affect on this
<img class="x" src="..."> <-------affect on this
 <img class="y" src="...">
<img class="x" src="..."> <-------affect on this
```

You can use the `id` for change one image ,(id is unique in html file):

> Affects any image that its `id` attribute value be `y1`:

```
#y1 { width:100%;}

 <img id="y1" src="..."> <-------affect on this
 <img id="y2" src="...">
 <img id="y3" src="...">
```

Answer (score 1):

The common solution to this problem is to use css classes or ids.

For example

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
img.some_image_class {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg">
<img class="some_image_class" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg">
```

Now it sounds like you may want to use selectors here.

For example

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <section id="sec1">
      </section>
      <section id="sec2">
         <img src="something" />
      </section>
     </body>
   </html>
```

```
#sec2 img {
  width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically use classes to better scope your styles.

```html
<img class="full-width" src="..." alt="...">
```

```css
img.full-width  {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

(Aside. Being that you can only have one id per element and you can have many classes `<img class="full-width other-class another-class" src="..." alt="...">` I've personally chosen to reserve the use of id's for JavaScript and keep all styles within classes. This way there are no issues later on and your javascript and CSS aren't dependent on the same names.

Ids are also useful for describing a section on the page for linking www.example.com/#id_to_scroll_to. Therefore, I'd want them to be descriptive of the content and not the styles.)